# Why is global $var not needed in these PHP functions?

Tags: php, php-5.5

I have a PHP system that doesn't define global scope for variables using  `global $var;` in functions and works on the server, but not on my local system.

Is this a change in PHP's scope rules or is there a setting that allows this?  My local system is running php 5.5.36, I don't know what version the server is running.

Edit: add code sample

This works on the server

```
include_once("common.inc.php"); // this defines $physical_path

class Admin extends AdminData
{
    function Admin($admin_auth_id='') {
        include_once($physical_path['DB_Access']. 'SubadminCommittee.php');
        // many more lines of code follow
    }
}
```

This works on local PHP running 5.5.36

```
include_once("common.inc.php"); // this defines $physical_path

class Admin extends AdminData
{
    function Admin($admin_auth_id='') {
        global $physical_path;  // why is this line not needed on server?
        include_once($physical_path['DB_Access']. 'SubadminCommittee.php');
        // many more lines of code follow
    }
}
```

Comment: Code sample please. We can't say anything about this based on a vague description.

Comment: @deceze I've added a code example, unfortunately I can't reproduce this off the server and I don't have a place there to create a simple example.  I did not create this system.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$physical_path` will ***not*** be available inside the function without `global`. This is not a difference in PHP versions or anything of that sort, it's a plain fact of scoping which does not differ between PHP versions.

The likely explanation is that `$physical_path['DB_Access']` evaluates to `null` and raises a warning, which you ignore. The `include_once` line therefore evaluates to just:

```
include_once('SubadminCommittee.php');
```

And this relative path lookup works on the server due to how the script is being invoked and what the current working directory there is. On your local server this doesn't work because your working directory differs and/or PHP's PATH value is set up differently.

Comment: I've set up a test class on the server and confirmed that the $physical_path variable is null.   as expected.  That variable is used for a lot of other things, so I'll need to add the global or replace it with a factory or singleton.

Comment: You should most certainly not use `global`; instead, dependency inject the value into every classes' constructor.

Comment: I would have used something other than a huge array of data in a global var, but that is the old PHP way.  I would have probably passed it as an argument or provided a singleton, or used Symfony to build the system and let it do the DI.